# Certain devices can't see my app in Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I've got the problem with my App. Certain of defices can't see my app in Google Play (e.g. Asus Nexus 1, Xperia E, Samsung Galaxy Tab GT5100). This all devices have android 4+, so SDK is compatible with minSDK.

This is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.merinosoft.photowallet"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.2.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />

    <application
        android:name="com.merinosoft.photowallet.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/MyHolo" >
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
        <activity
            ...
            <intent-filter>
                ...
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            ..
        </activity>
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
        <activity
            ...
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with that? I will be gratefull.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

You have a min version of 14. That means Android 4 and above. 
If you want to allow more devices to use it, you should target at least Android 2.2 and above. this is api level 8. Also i would raise android:targetSdkVersion to 17 or 18

```
    <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

After this, probably you will find some errors that you will need to fix, in order to be able to actually run in older devices

Comment: thanks, but I don't need to handle older devices. My app should works on devices with android 4.0+. My problem is in issue when I try to find this app on some devices with sdk 14+. Does increasing targetSdkVersion can resolve this problem?

Comment: probably, 14 is just 4.0, but im not sure if play will serve it also to newest devices.
Try it (even up to 19) and check the diference. If not, you will have to check all the declared features (when you upload the apk, play informs you) and think if some of them are not widely supported